# Add text in shape from other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a little issue. I figured out what the macro needs to be for the active worksheet but I want the same to happen in another worksheet. When I run the macro below it doesn't work. Could you guys have a look at it and tell me what is going wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Log

ws.Shapes("Rectangle 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "test " & Worksheets("Introductie").Range("D22") & " op " & Now()
ws.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 205, 50)

End Sub
```

If there any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: What is the variable `Log`? I can't see it as defined

Comment: @Andreas, my assumption was that `Log` is a sheets CodeName, which would work just fine. However, it could as well be the culprit but OP isnt very clear on what is going wrong other than "I want the same to happen in another worksheet".

Comment: @Andreas Log is the worksheet name

Comment: In that case that line should be `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")`